# EclipseLink - defining FetchType in the runtime

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

Lets say I have an entity with relation to other entity where FetchType is defined as EAGER

```
class Entity {
     @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
     @JoinColumn(name="user_profile_id")  
     private OtherEntity otherEntity;

}
```

This entity is being used in different Services and in some of the Services `FetchType.EAGER` on `OtherEntity` is what I want, however in some other Services I would be happy to change `FetchType` to `FetchType.LAZY`, however in my Entity class I've already defined `FetchType` on `OtherEntity` as `EAGER.

So the question is: is there a way to define `FetchType` in the runtime?

Thanks, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You normally wouldn't define something to default to 'eager' and then specify lazy at runtime as lazy requires special support to be woven in upfront, which isn't done on eager relationships.  Most would define it as lazy, and then use the [eclipselink.join-fetch](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_join_fetch.htm) query hint when it needs to be eagerly fetched in a single query.

You could also try [fetchGroups](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_fetchgroups.htm), this allows defining a [fetchGroup](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_fetchgroup.htm#BABJBDEG) to specify the attributes to be loaded.  I'm not sure it will override eager relationships, it might be worth trying, and it can be used to make the reverse case where you want to fetch certain lazy relationships easier.